# Android Ktor Client Localhost or Local IP Not Working

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

Trying to call a local server API from **Android** app using **Ktor** Client with **CIO** engine.

When I am using **localhost:8080** - at that time I am getting **Connection Refused** exception and when I am using **Local IP** address at that time I am getting **NoRouteToHostException**.

**localhost** and **Local IP** is working from **Postman**.

I am using **Ktor** Client version **2.3.4**

How I have to call the local server API using **Ktor** Client in **Android**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Every device is its own localhost. If you use localhost then the server is expected to run on the same device as the client.

Comment: What do you mean with 'Local IP'?

Comment: So tell where your server is running to begin with. And your Android app.

Comment: If your app is running on emulator then this will be local IP 10.0.2.2